# Register static S3 site with custom domain that is hosted on GoDaddy

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, dns

I have a static site on AWS S3 that I need to host on a custom domain. Unfortunately, that domain has already been registered on GoDaddy.

[this article](http://www.mikemurry.com/custom-domain-elastic-beanstalk/) tells how to deploy S3 for custom domain:

- Log into the Route 53 management console
- Open your Hosted Zone
- View the zone's record set
- etc...

Unfortunately, my `hosted zone` is not available on S3 as it is on GoDaddy.

So I have 2 questions:

1) How can I point an AWS S3 bucket to a domain that is registered/hosted on GoDaddy?

2) That article says I need to attach it to a load balancer. Since it's a static S3 site, I never created a Load Balancer for it. How can I configure the domain if there is no LB?

Comment: The linked article is about Elastic Beanstalk, not S3.

Answer (score 4):

To point your Godaddy domain to a S3 bucket you have to create a C-Name record for your domain www.dynamicdentaledu.com to point to your S3 bucket for www. See below screenshot.

[image]

And to point non-www domaindynamicdentaledu.com  to non-www bucket see below.

[image]

Comment: This doesn't seem to be working: www.dynamicdentaledu.com (S3 bucket name: `www.dynamicdentaledu.com.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com`). I've followed these instructions in AWS (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/website-hosting-custom-domain-walkthrough.html), and stopped at Step 3 (Route 53 Hosted Zones) because I am using GoDaddy for that stuff. In `GoDaddy`, I set CNAME `www`,  the Points to: [s3 bucket URL shown above], and TTL as 1 Hr. It's still sending me to GoDaddy

Comment: Dude your bucket name is dynamicdentaledu.com.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com and not www.dynamicdentaledu.com.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com you have setup a wrong C_Name

Comment: The docs state I should have 2 buckets... one with `www.etc...` one with`etc...`. `WWW.etc` points to `etc`

Comment: Check my edited answer. You will have to apply two records. First you will have to delete the A-Record for dynamicdentaledu.com and then add above second screenshot C-Name record for dynamicdentaledu.com

Comment: Do I have to add any CName records or do anything else in AWS S3?

Comment: Your site is working properly so you don't have to do any thing in s3, you just have to add above two records

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/123386/discussion-between-growler-and-error2007s).